# jquery .load() returns nothing if the string has a whitespace

Tags: php, jquery

I have a problem with `jquery` function `.load()`
I want to get the value from input field in `php`, but if you enter a whitespace in the field get nothing

here is my short code
html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <input type="text" onkeyup="$('#result').load('test.php?str='+$(this).val()).hide().fadeIn();" />
            <div id="result" ></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

and test.php

```
<?php
echo $_GET[str];
```

Comment: First point of call is examining the documentation for clues, which would point you to the behaviour of including whitespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have whitespace in that string, the latter chunk is [treated as a selector](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) for the returned HTML. If the selector doesn't match anything, nothing is returned.

You need to encode your parameter with `encodeURIComponent()`. This will ensure it won't end up with literal spaces, as they'll be encoded with `%20`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `encodeURIComponent` on `$(this).val()`.

Answer (score 1):

Write your javascript separatly

```
$('input[type=text]').keyup(function() {
    $('#result').load('test.php?str=' + encodeURIComponent($.trim($(this).val())) ).hide().fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: This will have the same bug.

Comment: You shouldn't post half-finished answers.

Comment: @alex - my bad, but at 1st I dont get where is problem, so I write advice, then I implement bugfix

Comment: Advice should be written in comments, and then correct answers as answers :)